# What happens when P controller's gain equals zero?

Tags: pid-controller, stability, control-theory

For example, I use Routh-Hurwitz Cirterion to examine the following system with P controller gain \$K\$:

$$\frac{{K\left( {2 - s} \right)}}{{{s^3} + 3{s^2} + 5s + 3}}$$

I closed loop it with \$H=1\$ and found that \$K\$'s BIBO stability range is

$$ - \frac{3}{2} < K < \frac{{12}}{5}$$

I think when \$K=1\$ then controller will be just ignored.

But what happened when \$K=0\$? Does that cause system unlink together?

What does it mean when \$K=0\$?

Why is \$K=0\$ still stable on the Routh-Hurwitz criterion?

Comment: suggest you post on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a different way to draw the proportionally-compensated closed-loop block diagram:

[image]

**The assumption behind the closed-loop block diagrams you know (like the one shown in PetPaulsen's answer above) is that K1=K2=Kp** If that's true you can simply replace K1 and K2 with a gain of Kp after the summer and you have the same mathematical relationship of inputs to ouptuts but just in the form you're used to.

So what happens when Kp=1?  Since Kp=K1=K2 we already know that K1 and K2 are 1.  The system is still compensated because the feedback gain (K2) is not zero. Thus, **in this form it's apparent that when Kp=1 the system is still compensated and the controller will not be ignored**. The above diagram shows what the canonical form can't show as clearly.  In this example, it's easy to see that the system only collapses to an uncompensated system if K2=0 and K1=1, but not if they're *both* 1.

Another of your questions was basically 'Why is Kp=0 considered 'stable'? Shouldn't that be 'disconnected' instead?'

It's something of a controls convention that zero gain represents an uncompensated system.  When you redraw the block diagram in the form I did you can begin to see the outlines of their thinking: if Kp=0, then K2=0 and feedback is broken and we're left with the uncompensated system.  But isn't K1 supposed to equal K2, which is 0?  Here's where a bit of fudging takes place (in my opinion).  They like mathematical continua and zero almost fits perfectly: if Kp is the smallest positive number, or the smallest negative number then you have a proportional controller. In fact if it's *anything* other than 0 it works - just not quite zero.  Unless you adjust your thinking: K1 only has to equal K2 when if you want a proportional feedback controller.  If you break the feedback you're under no obligation to have K1=K2, so let's just make it 1 and call it a day.

That still doesn't make it practical though. Trust me, if the 'correct' answer to a problem is a gain of Kp=0 you're having your leg pulled.

Answer (score 4):

There will be no input to the plant, if \$K = K_p = 0\$ (and \$K_i = 0, K_d = 0)\$.
The controller is ignored in this case (not if \$K = 1\$, because you still feedback the output).

[image: Block diagram]

(Original picture taken from [Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/PID_en.svg/800px-PID_en.svg.png) and modified)

With \$K = 0\$ the system is stable, because the equilibriums of your plant are stable.

---

Expanding based on your comment: The block diagram and the transfer funtions are just models for the system you want to describe. So for \$K=0\$ this could mean, that the controller is connected, but no control signal is applied to the plant (because you multiply by 0). Setting \$K=0\$ could also mean that the controller is not connected at all.
For example you want to simulate what happens, when the P-Controller fails. You could do this by setting \$K=0\$.

For \$K=1\$ the controller is *not* ignored. As long as you got the feedback you respond to changes in the output. Lets say \$v(t)\$ is the input to the plant.
$$v(t) = K_p \cdot e(t) = K_p \cdot (u(t) - y(t))$$
For \$K=1\$ you are still feeding back \$y(t)\$.
$$v(t) = e(t) = u(t) - y(t)$$
It would be wrong to say, that the controller wouldn't do anything. It just doesn't amplify the signal.

Comment: Oh, I maybe understand. Now I think K=0 means no input to plant but still connected with plant,right? K=1 means we still need plant to be acted and plant input = e(t). But does plant input=e(t) mean we just ignore controller and just connect wire from e(t) to the plant? Because in the case of controller=1,I think that controller doesn't do anything,right?

Comment: @sam - I tried to clarify your questions, hope this helps. If not, ask again.

Comment: Thank you for very detail explanation. Now I know K=0. For K=1, what you mean is controller is e(t), so controller couldn't be ignored? In case of controller = e(t), what I mean is its input = y(t) and u(t) ,and controller's operation is u(t)-y(t),so the controller's output=e(t).

Comment: If controller is not the above comment (e(t)). Is controller = 1, and its input=e(t) and controller just wired (means not do anything change to the input), and its output = e(t)? Thank you~

Comment: @sam - It's hard for me to understand your last two comments. You want to know whether the summation block (u(t) - y(t)) is part of the controller, right? -- Yes it is. y(t) comes from your sensors and u(t) what you want the output to be. This is all fed into the controller.

Comment: @sam - Another thing: I would realy recommend to you to read a book about the basics of control theory. Or if you already did, repeat it :)